# Facebook javascript-sdk Permission Dialog Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

Hi, i am puzzled about an Facebook-Error that has been recently popping up in my (newer) applications: The apps are working fine, until i disable sandbox mode and try to test the app as a normal user.

When clicking the login-button as normal user i get:
"An error occured. Please try again later" or sometimes : "API Error Description: An unknown error occurred Error Message: kError 1349045: An invalid Platform session was found.: An invalid Platform session was found."
Sometimes the normal Permission-Dialog shows up, but after asking the extended permissions i also get the error...

Here is my Code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//' + window.location.hostname + '/fbchannel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : false, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

};

    $(function(){
        $('.login').click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        $('#output').text('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#output').text('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, {scope: 'email, user_photos, publish_stream, user_likes'});

          // Additional initialization code here
        });
    });

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

I already tried enabling/disabling the enhanced auth dialog and the domain, facebook-app url and website is correctly set. For an admin of the app everything is working fine...
Does anybody have an idea what i have done wrong or have the same problems?

Comment: Why do you pass *false* for the cookie parameter in *FB.init*?

Comment: This was just for testing. cookie true is also not working...

Answer (score 0):

When you set up a facebook app you set up the urls from which it can be used.
My guess is that you are trying to load this page of yours from a domain different than the one in the facebook app settings.

In the facebook app settings, you should have something set in the *Website - Site Url*, you then need to load the page with the js sdk from the same domain.

If you want, you can set up other domains in the *App Domain* in the settings page, but all of the domains there *must be derived from your Site URL*.

I created a very simple page that only loads the js sdk and then tries to call the *FB.login*, I then tested it on the same domain as it is set for that app in the settings page, everything worked great.
I then copied that file to my localhost and gave it a try there, and indeed I received the same error you described.